# cast string to date (string may empty spaces in the DD position)

Tags: postgresql, date, types, casting, postgresql-9.5

I have a column with strings which look like this:

```
'201201  '
'19880324'
'        '
'176512  '
```

I need to cast them to date, but I cannot do it directly with `to_date('string', 'YYYYMMDD')` since some of the strings have empty spaces instead of DD and some other are only white spaces.

Solution tried:

```
ALTER TABLE dates ADD COLUMN dob_full DATE;
UPDATE test.dates
SET dob_full = CASE WHEN substring(partial_dob,1,1)=' ' THEN Null  -- if first char is empty string, nullify  
                    WHEN substring(partial_dob,1)='' THEN Null -- if whole string is empty string, nullify
                    WHEN substring(partial_dob,7,2)!='  ' THEN to_date(partial_dob, 'YYYYMMDD')  -- convert entire string to date
                    WHEN substring(partial_dob,7,2)='  ' THEN to_date(substring(partial_dob, 1, 6), 'YYYYMM')  -- slice string and convert to date
                    ELSE Null
               END;
```

Comment: You need to end a `CASE` statement with `END`: `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END`

Comment: Wrong link? You may need to save it first. Anyway my first thought would be to do something like: `UPDATE test.dates SET dob_full = CASE WHEN TRIM(partial_date) = '' THEN NULL ELSE TO_DATE(TRIM(partial_date), 'YYYYMMDD') END` - the "YYYYMMDD" is always valid on "YYYYMM" strings as long as they're not padded with whitespace, hence the second trim.

Comment: Thank you so much! Here's the correct db fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tix851Yzam8zms45UPjCUM/0#&togetherjs=ITs8soGRMF